# Нужен ли нам [microsoft]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Есть у нас метка [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) (большинство вопросов по которой заданы одним и тем же участником). Мне кажется, что это мусорная метка, которая нам не нужна: по отдельным продуктам этой компании существуют свои метки. На enSO, например, такая метка отсутствует.

P.S. Было бы также хорошо, если бы кто-то из модераторов подсказал вышеупомянутому участнику, что лепить метки [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) и [windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) к каждому вопросу по программированию не стоит.

Comment: [Подсказал.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570934/%d0%91%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-io-%d0%b2-c#comment751543_570934)

Comment: Метку windows встречаю часто совместно с метками различных языков программирования. Считаю, что она играет большую роль как дополнение, сразу понятно какой ОС касателен вопрос. Например c++ и windows. Я голосую против

Comment: Метку [tag:windows] имеет смысл ставить, когда вопрос специфичен для конкретной операционной системы. Да и то, скорее всего вместо windows нужно будет [tag:visual-c++] или там [tag:winapi]. В случае C#, например, метка [tag:windows] не нужна.

Comment: @VladD в VS можно и для [андроид/ios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn771552.aspx). А шарпы есть и под Mono. Так что смысл можно найти.

Comment: @alexolut: Да, я представляю себе случаи, когда эта метка _может_ быть полезной. Но в большинстве реальных случаев использования на сайте, думаю, она избыточна.

Comment: @MalovVladimir вопрос не о метке [tag:windows].

Comment: @VladD про `C# + windows` Вы высказались вполне определенно. Понятно что подавляющее большинство `C#` кода используется под вин, и можно предполагать метку `windows` по умолчанию, но что, если ситуация изменится (сомнительно, но кто знает).

Comment: @alexolut: Мой point в том, что windows имеет смысл писать лишь для специфических вопросов, в которых windows важна. Например, если вопрос по C# как языку, не опирающийся на его функционирование под Windows, то и метка не нужна. Если вопрос по использованию WinAPI, то логичнее метка [tag:pinvoke] или [tag:winapi], снова-таки не [tag:windows].

Comment: @VladD это уже несколько отличается от исходного `В случае C#, например, метка windows не нужна.`. P.S. не надо было автору в вопросе `windows` вообще упоминать :)

Comment: @alexolut нужно просто читать внимательнее. Я а) призывал образумить конкретного участника, б) говорил о том, что эта метка не нужна *к каждому* вопросу по программированию.

Comment: Так я ж с Вами и не спорю. У меня был диалог с @VladD. Так уж получилось, что в комментариях к Вашему вопросу. Не серчайте :)

Comment: Короче, я сжег все упоминания [tag:microsoft], но завис на этом [вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495891/Что-такое-подписка-msdn-и-для-чего-она-нужна). Помогайте :).

Comment: Можно добавить метку [tag:msdn], по крайней мере, такая есть на enSO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Метка [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) не нужна.

Метка [windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) нужна и неважно с каким языком, хоть и с C# или power shell, **если предполагается использовать хоть какие-то особенности ОС**.

Comment: Именно. Мы же не будем удалять метку `linux`, не так ли?