# Может удалим метку [microsoft]? (опять)

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Нашел метку [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) на [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/980752/319552) (и 9 других).

Описание гласит:

> НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ данную метку. Вместо неё используйте метки конкретных
>   продуктов, например [windows], [visual-studio], [azure].

На Мете также было [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3805/319552), где метку [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) признали ненужной. Но либо ее не удалили, либо кто-то снова создал. Что будем делать?

Comment: Было бы хорошо ее не только удалить, но и заблокировать от повторного создания.

Comment: @Kromster эта метка настолько вредная, что стоит ее выжечь и запретить пересоздание? А как насчет [tag:apple], [tag:google] и [tag:samsung]? Почему жечь и банить именно Microsoft, а не метки с названиями остальных крупных компаний?

Comment: @PashaPash отличное начинание, т.к. все перечисленные вами метки для тематики ruSO - это т.н. Мета-Метки - т.е. не имеющие сами по себе никакого смысла.

Comment: @Kromster с другой стороны - если 100+ участников использовало на своих вопросах метку apple - может быть их решение важнее десятка голосов на мете? :)

Comment: @PashaPash это плохая аргументация, т.к. у более чем 100 вопросов будут всевозможные метки типа "русская С", "плюсы", "ява", "помогите", "код", "программа", и не один десяток уже удаленных меток. Я клоню к тому, что метки это не "пусть ТС напишет что ему кажется", а способ категоризации вопросов и облегчения поиска по ним.

Comment: @Kromster чем именно наличие метки Microsoft или Apple ухудшает поиск и категоризацию? Вы можете привести конкретный пример, когда без метки Microsoft вопрос было бы легче найти, чем с ней?

Comment: @PashaPash вопрос должен быть "чем она их *улучшает*?".

Comment: @trollingchar не должен. изменения обязан обосновывать тот, кто их предлагает внести. Вы предлагаете потратить достаточно много ручного труда на чистку вопросов от меток, так что именно чистку нужно обосновать.

Comment: @PashaPash с этим немного не сходится то, что создание метки обосновывать необязательно, достаточно иметь 300 репутации. Но если чистить сложно, тогда наверно нужно обосновать.

Comment: Лишняя метка ухудшает вопросы тем, что занимает место (как физическое, так и количественное) и занимает/привлекает внимание, при этом не привнося никакой пользы.

Comment: @trollingchar такой низкий порог именно потому, что создание метки и установка ее на конкретный вопрос не требует значительных затрат. Для массовой чистки метка должна быть не просто бесполезна, она должна наносить вред. Причем прямой - путать участников, смешивать на себе разные понятия (как [tag:layout]), а не просто "занимать место"

Comment: @Kromster единственное место, где метка "занимает место" - это под вопросом, на котором она поставлена. И это занимание чисто субъективно. Для вас она "занимает место", а для сотни участников, которые ее поставили - наоборот, она "органично добавляет информацию". Кто прав?

Comment: Я бы наоборот, автоматизировал простановку подобных тегов. Чтобы участник мог скрыть всё от компании microsoft(например), не разбираясь в линейках его продуктов.

Comment: @PashaPash почему же число меток ограничено 5шт и длина метки ограничено НН символами? //*это наводящий риторический вопрос*//

Answer (score 8):

Сложный вопрос. Метка компании валидна, если у неё всего несколько продуктов. У MS куча продуктов, у каждого уже есть своя метка, та же [azure](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure), поэтому метка [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) совсем ни о чём и особо не помогает локализовать проблему.

С [samsung](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung) несколько иначе, т.к. на Android проблема может быть именно на линейке телефонов от этой компании.

Но, если рассуждать здраво, для чего нам метки? Чтобы каталогизировать и иметь возможность подписаться на нужные метки. Кто-то будет подписываться конкретно на метку [samsung](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung)? Вряд ли. К тому же, проблема может быть на линейке каких-то других устройств от Samsung (программируемый чайник с начинкой на Java?) и в итоге по этой метке какая-то мешанина будет.

Я лично за то, чтобы все эти [apple](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple), [samsung](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung), [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) сжечь.

Comment: `Кто-то будет подписываться конкретно на метку samsung?` Неправильный вопрос. Кто-то может **игнорировать** эту метку и подписаться на `android` без платформозависимых вопросов.

Comment: @vp_arth интересное замечание.

Comment: @vp_arth: а где же тогда метки `meizu`, `huawei` и тысячи других производителей, чтобы я мог *игнорировать их и смотреть только платформонезависимые вопросы*?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, это вопрос к авторам вопросов?

Answer (score 6):

Так как это я добавил в описание метки "Не использовать", и я удалял эту метку со многих вопросов, имеет смысл написать что-то.

Во-первых, она **действительно** была удалена тогда. Но ее создали снова, причем удаляли и пересоздавали уже несколько раз. Поначалу я удалял ее со всех вопросов, где ее видел (ну, чаще не удалял, а заменял на другие метки), но потом это надоело, и я решил добавить в описание "Не использовать" и оставлять в метке ~10 вопросов, чтобы описание не пропало.

Во-вторых, это **не** мета-метка. Она определенно несет некоторую информацию о тематике вопроса. Более того, она не вполне бесполезна, так как не под все продукты MS у нас есть метки. Представьте например, что пользователь хочет задать вопрос по какому-нибудь [Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/overview), по которому еще нет метки. Если метки [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) нет, скорее всего, пользователь поставит какую-нибудь совсем бессмысленную метку, типа [graph](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph), которая еще хуже. Далее, как заметил vp_arth, возможность игнорирования, но это в текущей реализации потребует пихать [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) на все вопросы по нему, даже если есть конкретная метка, что тоже не очень привлекательно. (Реальное решение проблемы - иерархическая система меток, но это уже за рамками данной темы.)

Но, по моему мнению, все эти плюсы не перевешивают тех проблем, которые эта метка создает:

- Она почти всегда занимает место других, более подходящих меток. Новички ставят [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), там где на самом деле должна стоять метка [windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), [visual-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), и т.п., и вопрос просто не находят те отвечающие, которые в нем заинтересованы. Число людей, которые хотят отслеживать конкретные продукты, куда больше, чем по технологиям MS в целом.
- Провоцирует некорректную простановку меток типа [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) + [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) вместо [sql-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). Уже кучу раз приходилось выправлять это.

Метки других компаний это несколько другая история. Для Samsung например, у нас нету конкретных меток типа [samsung-phone](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-phone), [samsung-monitor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-monitor), [samsung-hdd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-hdd), что там еще делает Samsung, со значительным числом вопросов и подписчиков. (Только не надо бросаться создавать!) Меток компаний много, все их не сжечь, но для наиболее популярных, на это можно пойти. В конце концов, на EN SO [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) [сожгли и занесли в черный список](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags). Есть какая-то причина не последовать этому? Я не думаю.

---

Словом, я за то, чтобы удалить и добавить в черный список. В качестве всплывающей подсказки при попытке добавления установить текст:

> Метка [microsoft] запрещена. Используйте вместо неё метки конкретных продуктов, например [windows], [visual-studio], [azure], [.net], [sql-server].

[apple](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) и [google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) также можно удалить, если поддержат те, кто отвечает по их технологиям (в отдельной теме, наверное).

Связанный вопрос: [Are company-name tags like microsoft and apple useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/are-company-name-tags-like-microsoft-and-apple-useful)

Comment: Пример с Graph плох. Надо создать метку [tag:microsoft-graph], чтобы она была однозначной и неделимой. Насчет [tag:google] спорно, т.к. эта метка очень релевантна для вопросов о поисковом-сайте Гугла, и заменить ее как-то нечем .. или ?

Comment: @Kromster это просто пример того, как технологии появляются быстрее, чем мы можем создавать под них метки, что дает некоторое преимущество (теоретически) в наличии более широких меток. Но если будут вопросы по нему, то да, конечно нужно будет создать [microsoft-graph].

Answer (score 4):

**Было бы хорошо ее не только удалить, но и заблокировать от повторного создания.**

---

> @Kromster эта метка настолько вредная, что стоит ее выжечь и запретить пересоздание? А как насчет apple, google и samsung? Почему жечь и банить именно Microsoft, а не метки с названиями остальных крупных компаний? – PashaPash♦

Все перечисленные вами метки, для тематики ruSO, это так называемые мета-метки - т.е. не имеющие сами по себе никакого смысла.

На эту тему на enSO мне встречался подстрочник, как проверить, что метка действительно нужна:

- соответствует ли метка тематике сайта? (например метка [котята](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0) нам явно не нужна)
- может ли метка быть самостоятельно использована на вопросе и описывать его, без применения других меток?
- могут ли быть в сообществе специалисты именно по этой метке?

[Дополнительно, описание процесса определения ненужности метки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)
[Инструкции по использованию меток, см. часть "Избегайте использования мета-меток"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

---

> Извините, но все перечисленные мной метки - не мета-метки. Мета-метки не описывают содержимое вопроса. Метка apple или microsoft, очевидно, описывает содержимое вопроса, хоть и косвенно. – PashaPash♦

В косвенном описании вопроса пользы нет, если при этом не присутствует уточняющей метки. А значит Мета-метка может быть безопасно удалена.

---

> Это не мета метка (выбирайте термины правильно), и специалисты по технологиям MS в целом, безусловно есть. Но поддерживаю удаление с занесением в черный список. – MSDN.WhiteKnight

Это как-раз таки мета-метка в тематике ruSO. Если бы у нас был сайт про историю компаний, или про финансы и торги - то да, она была бы полноправной и описательной. А в разрезе "программирования и системного администрирования" - она (и ее аналоги, типа apple) бесполезны.

Comment: Разве что по метке [tag:samsung] был вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/977321/319552 где проблема воспроизводилась только на устройстве от samsung, и были вопросы где эта метка единственная. Но вот метку [tag:galaxy] точно нужно удалить

Comment: Извините, но все перечисленные мной метки - не мета-метки. Мета-метки не описывают содержимое вопроса. Мета-метки не описывают содержимое вопроса. Метка apple или microsoft, очевидно, описывает содержимое вопроса, хоть и косвенно.

Comment: Это не мета метка (выбирайте термины правильно), и специалисты по технологиям MS в целом, безусловно есть. Но поддерживаю удаление с занесением в черный список.

Comment: Могут ли быть на SO специалисты по продуктам Microsoft - да, естественно, могут. Я специалист по продуктам MS, у меня даже сертификаты есть :) По продуктам от Google / Apple - тоже специалистов хватает

Comment: [tag:apple] тоже сжечь можно.

Comment: Вопросы с [tag:google], скорей всего, касаются поисковика. А вот [tag:microsoft] и [tag:apple] - вообще ни о чём. Хотя, и [tag:google] можно сжечь. А для поисковика есть [tag:google-search].

Comment: @PashaPash как специалист по Microsoft, разместите свой ответ и приведите пожалуйста примеры вопросов, в которых метки-"название компании" будут описательны и неотъемлимы.

Comment: @Kromster да легко. "как организовать отказоустойчивый кластер для хостинга веб приложений на стеке и продуктах от Microsoft". Очевидно, что  [tag:microsoft] на таком вопросе будет уместен.

Comment: @Kromster вообще и я, и MSDN.WhiteKnight указывали вам не на полезность  метки как таковой, а на неправильное использование вами термина мета-метка. Мета-метка - это конкретный термин, и перечисленные выше метки ему не соответствуют. От того, что вы начинаете называть просто не понравившиеся вам метки "мета-метками", они таковыми не станут, а вот термин "мета-метка" от этого размоется. Придут придут через пол года новые участники и начнут называть "мета-метками" те, которые они просто считают неуместными. А настоящие мета-метки под шумок будут плодится и размножаться.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо за пример. Есть сомнения: - не уверен, что такой вопрос не будет закрыт в течении получаса, как субъективный/общий; - метка [tag:microsoft] не сможет быть единственной на таком вопросе, другие метки будут важнее; - вам все равно придется расписать что такое стэк Микрософта; - вопрос, вероятно, будет проблемой-XY.

Comment: @PashaPash могли бы вы, пожалуйста, привести свое определение термина "мета-метка"? И дать определение перечисленным меткам, как их следует называть? А то мы тут о терминологии ломаем копья, вместо полезных дел. *P.S. Это нормально, что со временем у слов меняется смысл. Может быть в чат?*

Comment: @Kromster это проблема курицы и яйца. Ответ к такому вопросу - это указание на конкретные куски стека. Если автор вопроса знает конкретные куски стека и может их расписать - то он и вопрос и не задаст.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94632/discussion-on-answer-by-kromster----microsoft-).

Answer (score 4):

Метку [microsoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) [убрали со всех 45 вопросов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64404194#64404194) и заменили более подходящими.

Comment: Ура, мы знамениты. (c)