# Нужно сжечь [Мозиллу]

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Есть (была, пока я не удалил ее из всех 60+ вопросов) метка [mozilla](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla), которую беспорядочно ставили вместе или вместо [firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox), [thunderbird](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird), [gecko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gecko), и в принципе теоретически ее могут использовать для любого из продуктов [Mozilla](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_Mozilla).

Есть также недавнее (принятое!) предложение правки краткого описания метки, где [предлагается использовать эту метку для обозначения Mozilla Firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/867530) (при живой метке [firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox)).

Мое предложение:

- Сжечь (удалить окончательно и запретить создавать) метку [mozilla](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla)
- Для [firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox) добавить синоним [mozilla-firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla-firefox) (именно для этой метки, т.к. [mozilla](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) в большинстве случаев использовалась как синоним [firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox))

Answer (score 0):

Сделал метку [mozilla](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) синонимом [firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox).

Comment: Ok, I guess. Но это не синонимы.

Comment: @insolor будет ли это иметь значение для задающих вопросы? Если при использовании метки [mozilla] автор с высокой долей вероятности имел в виду [firefox].

Comment: @αλεχολυτ есть значение смысловое. mozilla не равно firefox. Ну и целом, про большинство: 4 из 5 будут конечно иметь в виду firefox. 1 из 5 будут иметь в виду что-то другое. Я предлагал именно добавить синоним mozilla-firefox, чтобы при вводе mozilla в метках предлагало firefox (как-то так я себе представляю), и участник выберет firefox, если он действительно имел в виду. А так получается кто-то будет иметь в виду какой-то другой продукт, а ему будет подставлять firefox.

Comment: @insolor сейчас уже сложно проверить, метку ж выпилили с вопросов :) по идее, если ТС заметит подмену, он её быстро поправит. А вообще метка [mozilla] - это та же [tag:microsoft] на минималках. Которую всё [хотят (но не могут) выпилить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9244/176217).

Comment: @insolor мы не можем запретить создать или использовать какую-либо метку. Самый простой способ добиться того что вы просили - сделать синоним.

Comment: @insolor запретить можем, но нужен сотрудник компании. [Пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/13107/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну и ладно, не так уж критично, пусть уже будет синонимом

Comment: @insolor по идее, можно сейчас отменить синоним (firefox - mozilla), тогда останутся только firefox, для него сделать синоним mozilla-firefox. И надеяться, что просто mozilla пока никто создавать не будет. Если явно через сотрудника не запретить.